# shell script hijacked my .htaccess files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, shell

Last night a shell script was able to execute some linux commands that modified my .htaccess files resulting in a simple redirect to an ad website. I've removed the redirect from the .htaccess but I'm trying to take preventative measures so that this does not happen again.

I viewed the access log from my server and it shows these entries below:

```
partners.xxxxxxxx.com-Jul-2016.gz:184.168.192.26 - - [03/Jul/2016:10:40:01 -0500] "GET /e5nbwvcxef.php HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0 SeaMonkey/2.26"
partners.xxxxxxxx.com-Jul-2016.gz:69.64.37.219 - - [03/Jul/2016:10:40:03 -0500] "POST /e5nbwvcxef.php HTTP/1.1" 200 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0 SeaMonkey/2.26"
```

I remember a little bit ago that if the user has this kind of access it is bad. Can anyone shed some light on tips I can do to secure my server so they cannot upload things like this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps better off asked on SU

Comment: @Wobbles what's SU?

Comment: You might want to post this over on Information Security Exchange: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry SF; http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Katie that is more for infosec.

Comment: @Wobbles, is there another? I'd be interested as well, on Security Stack Exchange they have a tag web-application that I have found useful for similar issues.

Comment: @Katie serverfault.com They are all part of the SE network and have the same functionalities.

Comment: @Wobbles - Thank you (sorry for missing your third message!) I'll check it out!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you want to prevent access to your `.htaccess` file, you can do that using:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

You can then actually rename your `.htaccess` file to help hide it from potential threats, it does not mean they can't find it.. but it certainly makes it harder!

```
AccessFileName thehtfile.ess
```

Then, there are a number of methods you can use to help prevent "hacks". First of all, block any scripts that include the `<script>` tag in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
```

You can then block any script trying to set a `PHP Globals` variable via a URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
```

Block any script trying to use `base64_encode` via URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR]
```

Block any script trying to modify the `a_REQUEST` variable via URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
```

Finally, disable the use of scripts on your directories..

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
```

Lots of different options, and I imagine there are a lot more! These are some of the ones I use in my `.htaccess`. I hope these help to prevent similar attacks in the future! It really does suck :/

Answer (score 1):

There are many points which should have been done [MySQL injection, ..] but very effective is

- the directory which contains your scripts must not be writeable by the `wwwrun` user.
- `.htaccess` should be accessible only by the root user - if possible. At least, the owner must not match the `wwwrun` user.

`wwwrun` user is the user under which Apache runs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused mainly because I normally do not enter the WHM. wwwrun is the default user for Apache, so it should not be able to write anything in the directory or have access to .htaccess correct? Essentially I should set up a permission for the default user in Apache.

Comment: @chronotrigga `wwwrun` must **not** have any write permission to the directory nor `.htaccess`. But of course, it must be able to read it - otherwise you can't execute anything. Therefore all files - including `.htaccess` - should have another owner.